# Fill Sinks keeps going from 1 to 100% over and over

Tags: qgis, sink

I’m working in QGIS on a 2021 MacBook Pro.

Trying to fill the sinks in my DEM - was initially trying to cover a large area but when Fill sinks failed to kick out an output, i created a smaller mosaiced DEM. However that is also not producing anything (it just keeps adding new lines with every rotation through the  Additionally the program keeps getting to ‘Application not responding’ stage.

In short, in the log window every time it goes from 0% to 100%, it adds a new empty line. Both when i was using my large data set and when i’m using my smaller one.

From what i’ve seen of other peoples ‘Fill Sinks’ this should take seconds if that so I don’t understand why it’s not.  I sat for hours waiting for it to load and it just kept adding lines.

Its also incredibly difficult to highlight the code - the software is running really really slowly.

```
QGIS code revision: 2a0a86f142
Qt version: 5.14.2
Python version: 3.8.7
GDAL version: 3.2.1
GEOS version: 3.9.1-CAPI-1.14.2
PROJ version: Rel. 6.3.2, May 1st, 2020
SAGA version 7.3.0 is not officially supported - algorithms may encounter issues
Algorithm started at: 2022-03-21T22:47:32
Algorithm 'Fill sinks' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'DEM' : '/private/var/folders/tl/60xc2m9n7dd09c5shbtfvfzm0000gp/T/processing_cKsIca/3f1d0018cf7a4c38928d9caed2c3965b/OUTPUT.tif', 'MINSLOPE' : 0.01, 'RESULT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT' }

io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM 1 -RESAMPLING 3 -GRIDS "/private/var/folders/tl/60xc2m9n7dd09c5shbtfvfzm0000gp/T/processing_cKsIca/612fdbc0181b48eeb9c7fae181884031/1.sgrd" -FILES "/private/var/folders/tl/60xc2m9n7dd09c5shbtfvfzm0000gp/T/processing_cKsIca/3f1d0018cf7a4c38928d9caed2c3965b/OUTPUT.tif"
ta_preprocessor "Fill Sinks (Planchon/Darboux, 2001)" -DEM "/private/var/folders/tl/60xc2m9n7dd09c5shbtfvfzm0000gp/T/processing_cKsIca/612fdbc0181b48eeb9c7fae181884031/1.sgrd" -MINSLOPE 0.01 -RESULT "/private/var/folders/tl/60xc2m9n7dd09c5shbtfvfzm0000gp/T/processing_cKsIca/a5284d4ef84645728445bda877f7506b/RESULT.sdat"
____________________________

##### ## ##### ##
### ### ## ###
### # ## ## #### # ##
### ##### ## # #####
##### # ## ##### # ##
____________________________

SAGA Version: 7.3.0

____________________________
library path: /Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/saga/
library name: libio_gdal
library : io_gdal
tool : Import Raster
identifier : 0
author : O.Conrad (c) 2007 (A.Ringeler)
____________________________



Parameters


Grids: No objects
Files: "/private/var/folders/tl/60xc2m9n7dd09c5shbtfvfzm0000gp/T/processing_cKsIca/3f1d0018cf7a4c38928d9caed2c3965b/OUTPUT.tif"
Multiple Bands Output: automatic
Select from Multiple Bands:
Transformation: true
Resampling: B-Spline Interpolation


loading: /private/var/folders/tl/60xc2m9n7dd09c5shbtfvfzm0000gp/T/processing_cKsIca/3f1d0018cf7a4c38928d9caed2c3965b/OUTPUT.tif



Driver: GTiff
Bands: 1

Rows: 5000

Columns: 13500


loading: OUTPUT




____________________________

##### ## ##### ##
### ### ## ###
### # ## ## #### # ##
### ##### ## # #####
##### # ## ##### # ##
____________________________

SAGA Version: 7.3.0

____________________________
library path: /Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/saga/
library name: libta_preprocessor
library : ta_preprocessor
tool : Fill Sinks (Planchon/Darboux, 2001)
identifier : 3
author : Copyrights (c) 2003 by Volker Wichmann
____________________________

Loading grid: /private/var/folders/tl/60xc2m9n7dd09c5shbtfvfzm0000gp/T/processing_cKsIca/612fdbc0181b48eeb9c7fae181884031/1.sgrd...




Parameters


Grid system: 2; 5000x 13500y; 290001x 200001y
DEM: 1
Filled DEM:
Minimum Slope [Degree]: 0.010000
```

Comment: I recommend you to run those processes directly in SAGA GIS, which is installed in the same folder as QGIS. It is simple and will give you better results.

Comment: Another thing, I see that you are applying only fill sinks (Planchon's method), I recommend you to apply the Fill Sink Wang &Liu method. And if it is a very dense digital model, with a large size, apply Fill Sink Wang &Liu XL.